# regex to find the position of the first four concurrent unique values

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I've solved 2022 [advent of code day](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/6) 6, but was wondering if there was a regex way to find the first occurance of 4 non-repeating characters:

From the question:

**bvwbjplbgvbhsrlpgdmjqwftvncz**

**bvwb**jplbgvbhsrlpgdmjqwftvncz

# discard as repeating letter b

b**vwbj**plbgvbhsrlpgdmjqwftvncz

# match the 5th character, which signifies the end of the first four character block with no repeating characters

in R I've tried:

```
txt <- "bvwbjplbgvbhsrlpgdmjqwftvncz"
str_match("(.*)\1", txt)
```

But I'm having no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_extract(txt, "(.)(?!\\1)(.)(?!\\1|\\2)(.)(?!\\1|\\2|\\3)(.)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8nLmE/1). Here, `(.)` captures any char into consequently numbered groups and the `(?!...)` negative lookaheads make sure each subsequent `.` does not match the already captured char(s).

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/rQyx4j):

```r
library(stringr)
txt <- "bvwbjplbgvbhsrlpgdmjqwftvncz"
str_extract(txt, "(.)(?!\\1)(.)(?!\\1|\\2)(.)(?!\\1|\\2|\\3)(.)")
## => [1] "vwbj"
```

Note that the `stringr::str_match` (as `stringr::str_extract`) takes the input as the first argument and the regex as the second argument.

Comment: Which leads nicely to a 4 line answer to AOC day 6: 
n <- 4
pastereg <- \(o, i){paste(o, i, sep = "|\\")}
reg <- paste0(paste0("(.)(?!\\", accumulate(1:(n-1), pastereg), ")", collapse=""), "(.)")
str_locate(txt, reg)[,"end"]